# What is the relationship between the global io.sockets and the socket in its callback function

Tags: socket.io

as the title mentioned, I have code like(part of):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("Connection " + socket.id + " accepted.");
  socket.on('message', function(message){
        console.log("Received message: " + message + " - from client " + socket.id);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Connection " + socket.id + " terminated.");
  });
});
```

I have no idea what exactly they are, can someone give me some detail and example how to use them in real case? Such as how to refer to specific socket connection?

Thanks

Comment: which language are you asking about?

Comment: @levengli it is Javascript. I want to try express3 and socket.io